# Optimize C or assembly code in size for Cortex-M0

Tags: c, optimization, cortex-m

I need to reduce the code bloat for the Cortex-M0 microprocessor.

At startup the ROM data has to be copied to the RAM data once. Therefore I have this piece of code:

```
void __startup( void ){
  extern unsigned int __data_init_start;
  extern unsigned int __data_start;
  extern unsigned int __data_end;

  // copy .data section from flash to ram
  s = & __data_init_start;
  d = & __data_start;
  e = & __data_end;
  while( d != e ){ 
    *d++ = *s++;
  }
}
```

The assembly code that is generated by the compiler looks like this:

```
  ldr   r1, .L10+8
  ldr   r2, .L10+12
  sub   r0, r1, r2
  lsr   r3, r0, #2
  add   r3, r3, #1
  lsl   r1, r3, #2
  mov   r3, #0
.L4:
  add   r3, r3, #4
  cmp   r3, r1
  beq   .L9
.L5:
  ldr   r4, .L10+16
  add   r0, r2, r3
  add   r4, r3, r4
  sub   r4, r4, #4
  ldr   r4, [r4]
  sub   r0, r0, #4
  str   r4, [r0]
  b .L4
```

How can I optimize this code so the code size is at minimum?

Comment: What compiler do you use? What compiler flags? Have you considered writing it in assembly?

Comment: It's now 18*4 = 72 bytes. How much effort do you want to put into it to make it yet even smaller?

Comment: `s = & __data_init_start;` I don't think you want the `&` here; `__data_init_start` already appears to be an address constant. (and the other two `&` neither)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler (or you!) does not realize that the range to copy is `end - start`. There seems to be some unnecessarily shuffling of data going on -- the 2 `add` and the `sub` in the loop. Also, it seems to me the compiler makes sure that the number of copies to make is a multiple of 4. An obvious optimization, then, is *to make sure* it is in advance! Below I assume it is (if not, the `bne` will fail and happily keep on copying and trample all over your memory).

Using my decade-old ARM assembler knowlegde (yes, that is a major disclaimer), and post-incrementing, I think the following short snippet is what it can be condensed to. From 18 instructions down to 8, not too bad. If it works.

```
  ldr   r1, __data_init_start
  ldr   r2, __data_start
  ldr   r3, __data_end
  sub   r4, r3, r2
.L1:
  ldr   r3, [r1], #4  ; safe to re-use r3 here
  str   r3, [r2], #4
  subs  r4, r4, #4
  bne   L1
```

Answer (score 1):

May be that platform guarantees that writing to an `unsigned int *` you may change an `unsigned int *` value (i.e. it doesn't take advantage of type mismatch aliasing rules).

Then the code is inefficient because `e` is a global variable and the generated code logic must take in account that writing to `*d` may change the value of `e`.

Making at least `e` a local should solve this problem (most compilers know that aliasing a local that never had its address taken is not possible from a C point of view).